# Mainboard gives signs of live again, but doesn't do a POST

Tags: bios, gpu, thinkcentre

This is a follow up to this thread: [Did I just blow up my mainboard, or is it something else?](https://superuser.com/questions/292696/did-i-just-blow-up-my-mainboard-or-is-it-something-else)

I managed to get the mainboard to do something more than putting all fans in a low speed. I left the CMOS battery out for two days, to be certain that everything's really gone. Now the system "starts" when I put in the power cord (a good sign, in my system after a power failure it is set to power on again when power is restored, this didn't happened when the mainboard was "dead"...).

The only thing is: it doesn't do anything except starting to blow very, very heavily. Okay, it's quite hot in here due to the summer, but not that hot to blow at about 60dB. And all what comes out is cold air. I get no POST beeps, and no other signs of life.

I tried to power it on without any hardware (only CPU, and PSU attached), so I could hear the memory error beeps. They didn't come. Only a big noisy blowing sound ;-).

I tried to power it on, with the hardware it should mimimum require: RAM, CPU, PSU. Same as above.

I tried to put in a GeForce G210 card, which worked before in that machine, same result.

I tried to add/remove various other parts, like Floppy drive (required for BIOS recovery procedure, which I was required to follow a few hours before it broke), DVD drive, HDD drives, TV card,...

I did recover the BIOS, because it was partially nulled, before the symptoms of the previous post arise, to make sure the issue with the HD5770 was not a BIOS issue (IBM listed a fix for PCI-e related problems). The BIOS was succesfully recovered, it booted about 10 times, with all the expected beeps (1 when POST succeeded, 4-2-3-3 beeps for "Extended Block Move" when GPU inserted).

I also found a thread on a similar PC like me, which states that no 5xxx cards work on my computer. ( http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/A-and-M-Series-ThinkCentre/M58p-4-2-3-3-beep-code-with-MSI-HD-R5770-graficscard-PCIe-x16/td-p/215948 )

How do I put out the noise, and get the mainboard back in business ;-)? Which other options can I try? Which ATI GPUs of the mid range (100-150 EUR) would work on this mainboard? Should a 6xxx series work, because on the Lenovo forums is listed that 6xxx won't work, but nothing about a 6xxx.

-y

Answer (score 2):

Don't buy anything just yet. Borrow one or two cards and try them on to see if they work. most PCI-e cards should be compatible with your board.

At this point, you've ruled out CPU, RAM and PSU.

If it still doesn't work, just throw your motherboard away. Those things aren't meant to be repaired by humans, only by robots with very tiny fingers.

Answer (score 0):

If you pulled the RAM and video and didn't get any POST error beeps then your motherboard is more than likely toast.  It MIGHT be the CPU, but that's very rare, whereas dead motherboards happen quite a bit.